# sed: -e expression #1, char 56: unknown option to `s'

Tags: command-line, text-processing, sed

I have several directories and sub-directories include text files. I need to change particular line of these text files for all directories and sub-directories. I used below sed command to perform this task;

```
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/old_line/new_line/g' {} \;
```

It is working if there is no space in old_line and new_line. But it doesn't work for below example;

```
old_line=5704550660          SPP91564_2                              ANT # / TYPE

new_line=5704550660          SPP91564_2      NONE                    ANT # / TYPE
```

when I append these lines within above sed command, I receive;

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 56: unknown option to `s'
```

How can I modify above command to work properly for above example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not the spaces that's causing the problem, but the `/` in the text. Your command reads: `sed 's/570455066 .../ TYPE/5704550660.../ TYPE/g'` - do you see the problem? You need to use a different character as the delimiter which doesn't appear in the replacement text, say `:`

```
sed 's:5704550660          SPP91564_2                              ANT # / TYPE:5704550660          SPP91564_2      NONE                    ANT # / TYPE:g'
```

You can also just escape the `/` in the text with a backslash: `\/`.